# c++ *& dereference address of operator?

Tags: c++, pointers

In a recent assignment for a data structures class, we we're expected to use this "*&" in a function parameters list. I am having trouble finding info on why this exists, and even what it does. Is it standard practice to use this?

Here's a code snippet

```
template <class T>
Thing <T> * action(const T &dataIn, Thing <T> *& thingIn)
{
    if(thingIn == NULL)
    {
        Node <T> *newThing = new Thing <T> (dataIn);

        newThing->ptr = thingIn;
        thingIn= newThing ;

        return(newThing );
    }
}
```

I guess another part of my question is, why use "*&" at all couldn't you just send the pointer?

Comment: It's for passing pointer parameters by reference.

Comment: I doubt it's only `*&`. What's the type in front of it? `char*&` or `int`*&` or something else? Or is it only `T&`? Or is it something like `&p` in the function body? You should provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

It is used for a reference type pointing to a pointer

Example

```
int *&ref = ptr;
```

in the above example, `ref` is a reference to an `int` pointer `ptr`

which then can be passed in to a function

```
function(int *&ref)
```

Answer (score 2):

fun(int x)

fun takes an int value

fun(int* x)

fun takes an int pointer by value

fun(int& x)

fun takes an int by reference

fun(int*& x)

fun takes an int pointer by reference - the value of the pointer to x as seen by the caller can be changed by fun

Comment: Please at least bother to put the code inside code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a structure for example like

```
struct A
{
    //...
};
```

then a function parameter can look like

```
void f( A * &pa );
```

In this declaration `A *` means pointer type and `&` means that this pointer is passed to the function by reference.

Compare these two code snippets

```
void f( A * &pa )
{
    pa = new A();
}

//...


A *p = nullptr;

f( p );
```

After calling the function the variable `p` will have the address of the allocated memory in the function because it was passed to the function by reference.

If the function would be declared like this

```
void f( A * pa )
{
    pa = new A();
}

//...


A *p = nullptr;

f( p );
```

then after calling the function the pointer `p` would not be changed because the function deals with a copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

let's look into this:

```
void fun( int i );
```

we pass parameter by value, it means function can use `int i` but cannot change variable that is used to pass that value:

```
void fun( int i ) { i = 123; }

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    fun( j ); 
    std::cout << j << std::endl; // j is still 0
}
```

on another side when we use refernce, variable would be changed:

```
void fun( int &i ) { i = 123; }

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    fun( j ); 
    std::cout << j << std::endl; // j is 123 now
}
```

if you understand this concept you should be able to undestand more complex types, just use `typedef` or more modern `using`:

```
 typedef char * pchar;
 fun( pchar &p );
 fun( char *&p ); // this is the same as before
```

you can actually use it in program or at least in your mind, that should simplify your understanding that a pointer is the same variable as anything else. It also helps to understand other complex types like pointer to pointer etc.

Comment: You should capitalize the begginings of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> In a recent assignment for a data structures class, we we're expected to use this "*&" in a function parameters list. I am having trouble finding info on why this exists, and even what it
>   does.

C++ declarations can be **read from right to left**. It's a reference to a pointer.

> Is it standard practice to use this?

Not really. See below.

> I guess another part of my question is, why use "*&" at all couldn't you just send the pointer?

A reference allows you to modify the object which is being referenced.

A pointer is an object. So a reference to a pointer allows you to modify a pointer. Modifying a pointer means to **make it point somewhere else**. So if you take a `*&` in a function, then it means that the function can change where the pointer *outside of the function* points to.

Changing the destination of a raw pointer is not something you do very often in C++, but as always, it depends on your application domain.

Changing the destination of an existing pointer certainly feels more like C-style programming, and there are no references in C. In C, you would use `**` instead of `*&` to accomplish this, and pass a pointer to a pointer, accordingly.